# GenJar replacement or update?

Tags: java, jar, packaging

"GenJar is a specialized Ant task that builds jar files based on class dependencies rather than simply the contents of a directory" (http://genjar.sourceforge.net/)

It is really useful, but the project seems to be un-active
since "2003-03-06      GenJar 1.0.2 is released".

Is there a new tool for that we should use now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

genjar2 seems to be the "official" replacement:
http://code.google.com/p/genjar2/

Answer (score 0):

How about maven http://maven.apache.org/?

Comment: Too complicated. (Have you seen the pom.xml file?)
maven is for the whole project organization, not
simply choosing what .class files pack into a .jar